# Receiving this Error with RPi camera module: mmal received unexpected camera control callback event

Tags: camera, raspicam

This error appeared two weeks ago when using the camera module.  I searched on the internet and came to a conclusion that my Raspberry Pi camera module was defective.

I just received another camera module, earthed myself and connected it to RPi but the same error appeared, namely:

```
mmal received unexpected camera control callback event
```

I'm really frustrated, I have a project on RPi need to be done this Tuesday :( Help please

Answer (score 1):

try this tutorial [ https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/435 ].

the most common problem is that the 1-wire module overwrite the gpio function selection for the I2C pins.

verify that :

ensure that  i2c-bcm2708 is blacklisted in your `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` (uncomment it if commented)

```
blacklist spi-bcm2708
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

The modules are in this order in your `/etc/modules`

```
w1-gpio
w1-therm
i2c-bcm2078
i2c-dev
```

Comment: I did the changes in the second file /modules (already found them blacklisted in the fisrt one)
now i'm getting these errors:
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

Comment: you know, I have the same problem, and I tried to fix it for 2 months, people that follows this answer said that it works fine, but not for me. so I decided to return the camera to the store, sorry

Comment: as i mentioned above i did get a new camera module with the same frustrating result! i'm afraid that its a csi problem in the RPi board :( thanks anyway